# html5 video requires refresh to play

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to load a video using the following code, but it never loads first time.

```
<video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="IMG_1234.MOV" preload></video>
```

Any idea why this might happen (and whether it's fixable)? I've tried in Safari and Chrome on a Mac and Safari on an iPad.

It usually loads on the first refresh but sometimes requires a few tries.

Answer (score 0):

I know this works I tried it prior to posting: I would lower case the *.mov
and be sure the path is complete. the additional type="video/mov" provides proof positive that mov is a video file to be played.

> < video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" name="IMG_1234.mov" > src="IMG_1234.mov" type="video/mov" preload>

you can also use  if you want an auto start. it is not a fuction of all browsers though.
( do not leave the space after the < and video. That was done to allow posting of the code.